# Minimal Polynomial of a scalar multiple of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I got the following problem:

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ over field $\mathbb{F}$
and let $M_A$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$ of degree $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $0\neq c\in\mathbb{F}$ be any nonzero scalar in $\mathbb{F}$ then the minimal polynomial of $cA$ denoted by $M_{cA}$ is equal to
$c^nM_A({\frac tc})$ or $c^kM_A({\frac tc})$

I tried to prove it but didn't manage to continue that much.

 Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed your guests are in the right direction: $M_A(\frac{t}{c})$ annihilates $cA$, which is the first property the minimal polynomial of $cA$ must fulfil.

The second one is that it must be *monic*; that is, its leading coefficient must be equal to one. Hence you need to multiply it by $c^k$.

Finally, you need to prove that, if $P(t)$ is such that $P(cA) = 0$, then $M_{cA}\ | \ P$. And this is the case, since $P(cA) = 0$ means that $P(ct)$ annihilates $A$. Hence, $M_A (t)\ | \ P(ct)$. Now, we do a little change with the name of the variable: put $u = ct$ and you get $M_A(\frac{u}{c}) \ | \ P(u)$. That is, $M_{cA} \ | \ P$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial such that $f(cA) = 0$. Then $g(x) = f(cx)$ is a polynomial such that $g(A) = 0$, and hence, by definition of the minimal polynomial, $g(x)$ is divisible by $M_A(x)$, i.e., $g(x) = q(x)M_A(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. What does this, then, imply for $f(x) = g(x/c)$?