# Write $m_{I-A}$ (the minimal polynomial of $I-A$) in terms of $m_A$ and conclude: $\deg(m_A)=\deg(m_{I-A})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials, cayley-hamilton

Given a matrix $A$ and its minimal polynomial $m_A$.

> Write $m_{I-A}$ (the minimal polynomial of $I-A$) in terms of $m_A$ and conclude: $\deg(m_A)=\deg(m_{I-A})$

Any hint or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\deg m_A = k$ then $$m_{I-A}(x) = (-1)^k m_A(1-x)$$

Indeed, we have that $(-1)^k m_A(1-x)$ annihilates $I - A$ so $m_{I-A}(x) \,| \,(-1)^k m_A(1-x)$.

Also note that  $m_{I-A}(1-x)$ annihilates $A$ so $m_A(x) \,| \,m_{I-A}(1-x)$.

Therefore $\deg m_A = \deg_{I-A}$ so $(-1)^k m_A(1-x)$ is monic polynomial of the same degree as $m_{I-A}$ which annihilates $I-A$. By minimality, we conclude that $m_{I-A}(x) = (-1)^k m_A(1-x)$.

Comment: @GalushBalush $|$ means divides. $p \,|\,q $ if there exists a polynomial $r$ such that $pr = q$.

Comment: How did you find this polynomial? and why is $m_{I-A}(1-x)$ annihilates $A$ true? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GalushBalush In general we have $m_{A - \lambda I}(x) = m_A(x + \lambda)$ and $m_{cA}(x) = c^k m_A\left(\frac{x}c\right)$ if $\deg m_A = k$ so I just combined these two facts. Just evaluate $m_{I-A}(I-A) = 0$.

Comment: I have never learnt these properties of the minimal polynomial. Where can I find them?

Comment: @GalushBalush Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/623859/144766) for the second one. They are also evident from the spectral mapping theorem because $\sigma(A - \lambda I) = \sigma(A) - \lambda$ and $\sigma(c A) = c\sigma(A)$. Then use that that the zeros of the minimal polynomial are precisely the eigenvalues.